# Hemisphere containing the maximum number of points scattered on a sphere

Tags: computer-science, computational-geometry, integer-programming

Consider a set of points $x_1, \ldots,x_n$ on $\mathbb{S}^{k-1}$ (the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^k$). The goal is finding the hemisphere which contains the maximum number of $x_i$'s. Basically, we would like to find the hyperplane passing through the origin, which contains the maximum number of $x_i$'s on one side. Any pointers to equivalent problems, or (in)exact algorithms?

Comment: Cross-posted: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/435151/hemisphere-containing-the-maximum-number-of-points-scattered-on-a-sphere

Answer (score 4):

You can solve the problem via mixed integer linear programming as follows.
Let continuous decision variables $\beta_j$ be the coefficients of the desired hyperplane, and let binary decision variable $y_i$ indicate whether $x_i$ is in the hemisphere defined by $\sum_{j=1}^k \beta_j z_j \le 0$.  The problem is to maximize $\sum_{i=1}^n y_i$ subject to
\begin{align}
\sum_{j=1}^k \beta_j x_{ij} &\le M_i(1-y_i) &&\text{for $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$} \tag1\label1\\
-1 \le \beta_j &\le 1 &&\text{for $j\in\{1,\dots,k\}$} \tag2\label2
\end{align}
Constraint \eqref{1} enforces the logical implication $y_i = 1 \implies \sum_{j=1}^k \beta_j x_{ij} \le 0$.
Constraint \eqref{2} is an optional normalization, which is valid without loss of optimality; you can always divide both sides of the hyperplane inequality by the absolute value of the largest coefficient.

In the big-M constraint \eqref{1}, the constant $M_i$ is a (small) upper bound on the LHS when $y_i=0$.  Because of \eqref{2}, you can take
$M_i = \sum_j |x_{ij}|$.

Comment: thanks for the note. Are you aware of any greedy/inexact algorithms to solve this problem? Something except relaxing the binary $y_i$ as $0\leq y_i\leq 1$.

Comment: As an approximation, you could first cluster the points. Then the $y_i$ variable corresponds to (the centroid of) each cluster instead of each point, and the objective is to maximize $\sum_i n_i y_i$, where $n_i$ is the number of points in cluster $i$.

Comment: Actually, there is a major problem with the MIP approach above. It always offers the trivial solution $\beta_j=0$ and $y_i=1$.

Comment: Yes, sorry. We must avoid that solution for $\beta$, so try normalizing via constraint $\sum_j \beta_j =1$ and separately try $=-1$.

Answer (score 0):

A simple and fast inexact (heuristic) algorithm would be:

**Step 1**. Compute the [centroid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid) $C$ of the point set $\{x_1,x_2,...,x_n\}$.

**Step 2**. Let's say the $O$ is the center of the unit sphere. Then the normal vector ${C-O}$ will define the hyperplane you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\sigma:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow(a,b)$ be a continuous increasing bijection ($\tan^{-1},\tanh$ are suitable functions). Let $L_{x_1,\dots,x_n}:\mathbb{R}^k\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be the function defined by
$L_{x_1,\dots,x_n}(w)=\sum_{k=1}^n\sigma(\langle x_k,w\rangle)$. We can then find a value $w$ that nearly maximizes $L_{x_1,\dots,x_n}$ using gradient ascent, and $w$ will typically be normal to the hyperplane you are looking for since if we find $w$ that nearly maximizes $L_{x_1,\dots,x_n}(w)$, then $w$ will most likely also maximize $\sum_{k=1}^n\text{sgn}(\langle x_k,w\rangle)$.

Gradient calculations: If you do not want to calculate the gradients by hand, then programming languages (like Python or Julia) where you can easily use automatic differentiation should be used to calculate this gradient. Otherwise, the gradient is just $\nabla_w L_{x_1,\dots,x_n}(w)=\sum_{k=1}^n\sigma'(\langle x_k,w\rangle)\cdot x_k$.

This gradient ascent method should give better results than simply using the hyperplane normal to $x_1+\dots+x_n$.

Comment: If we initialize $w=0$, then the first step of the gradient ascent will give us HEKTO's answer. In my computer experiments, I usually got much better results than one can obtain in just one step of gradient ascent.